# Simple IE7 fix for li:hover

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I've searched all over for a simple solution to this but I can't find one that fits.

All I want to do is show a simple span element when someone hovers over the li parent but obviously IE7 has other plans.

Surely there's a simple javascript solution?

```
.locations ul.menu li span{background:url('images/phone-bg.png') no-repeat;width:89px;height:34px;display:none;position:absolute;margin:-36px 0 0 10px;padding:4px 3px 0 3px;color:#000;font-size:11px}

.locations ul.menu li:hover span{display:inherit}
```

Comment: Does it work if you have it shown first and then when you hover, it disappears, so potentially swapping around display:none and inherit

Comment: have you tried all the display methods, like block, inline-block?

Comment: Oddly it seems to work now, I've not done anything new. The quirks of IE I suppose :p

Comment: talking about quirks, maybe your browser was in quirk mode? See my answer below :)

Comment: Nope, it was in standards mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your browser isnt in Quirks or any other funny mode under Internet Explorer Development Tools.

You can add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to the top of your pages to ensure it always uses the latest version.

`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx`

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline`, not `display: inherit`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make :hover work on non-link elements in IE7, make sure you're using a strict doctype, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

is the HTML5 doctype.

IE7 only uses the old :hover behaviour when it's in quirks mode.

Comment: I am using the HTML5 doctype, I tried with every other doctype that I could think of and still nothing seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

you can add following line at the top of your html file.
it works for me in ie 9.0

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```